# Session gets overridden on opening a new tab in IE in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a home page url http://localhost:3443/home1
In the index action of home1 I am having a session["Home"]=Home1.
I am having another home page url http://localhost:3443/home2
There i have a session session["Home"]=Home2.

Now the context is for some user the landing page is home1. So if they click on home button on the menu or or do any such activity they should land into home1.

For another set of users they should land into home 2 for whatever activity they do which leads to the home page.

Now the menu.it is a ascx control
Here we are checking the session value is home1 or home2.
Based on that we are redirecting the user to the desired landing page.
Now the problem that I am facing is when we copy
http://localhost:3443/home1 to another tab e.g. tab2 and from there we change it into home2 and then do some activity. And then come back to tab1, what happens the value gets overridden it taken the home2 session. Which leads to the wrong landing page on click of home link in the menu. Do you have any solutions for this problem?

I hope i have correctly explained the problem if not please let me know,I will explain further.

Answer (score 0):

Session is for the connection which will include both tabs (for example why you can login to stackoverflow on one tab and then if you open a second tab you are still logged in)

Answer (score 0):

As @Skuld mentioned, the session is for user connection to the site so if the user goes to another page he or she is allowed to go they can open this in a new tab keeping the original tab open, if these are form pages you might want to look at 14 AntiForgeryToken. also i noticed you said this happens in IE does this also happen in Chrome? if so you might want to look to see if IE is excepting cookies. you can add roles to the session and then authorize those roles to home1 or home 2 from your controller, you should be authorizing users and roles to pages in your code not within your session. its hard to help any more without any code to look at.

Hope this gets you on the right track.